# Android instrumented test throws exception: Activity never becomes requested state "[RESUMED, DESTROYED, STARTED, CREATED]"

Tags: java, android, xiaomi, instrumented-test

This is the shortest variant of the test:

```
…
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class RunAllTest {
  @Test
  public void testShortRun() {

    Context ctx = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, SplashActivity.class);

    ActivityScenario activityScenario = ActivityScenario.launch(intent);
  }
}
```

It throws an exception:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Activity never becomes requested state "[RESUMED, DESTROYED, STARTED, CREATED]" (last lifecycle transition = "PRE_ON_CREATE”)

Mobile phone model: Xiaomi Redmi 9

MIUI version: MIUI Global 11.0.7 Stable 11.0.7.0(QJCRUXM)

Android version: 10 QP1A.190711.020

Android security patch level: 2020-09-01

### **Founded solution/workaround:**

you should disable (enabled by default)

*Settings -> Additional settings -> Developer options -> Turn on MIUI optimization*

Comment: i have device xiaomi redmi 4, but disabling MIUI optimization from developer option didn't help me

Comment: @PriteshVishwakarma, I am also facing the same issue. Found any solution?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/68534534/9636037