# AssertionError: Activity never becomes requested state "[DESTROYED, STARTED, RESUMED, CREATED]" (last lifecycle transition = "PRE_ON_CREATE")

Tags: android, android-emulator, travis-ci, android-espresso, android-lifecycle

I recently updated the [Travis CI configuration](https://app.travis-ci.com/github/Umweltzone/Umweltzone/jobs/547682552/config) for my [Android application project](https://github.com/Umweltzone/Umweltzone) (Android Gradle Plugin 7.0.3, targetSdk 30, JVM 11) to use the new [command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/#command-tools). I have chosen `system-images;android-19;google_apis;armeabi-v7a` to start an emulator to run the instrumentation tests. I am using `androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0`.

The emulator boots and executes the instrumentation tests via `connectedDebugAndroidTest` but all fail with the following error:

```
AboutActivityTest > renderBuildInformation[test(AVD) - 4.4.2] FAILED 
  java.lang.AssertionError: Activity never becomes requested state 
  "[DESTROYED, STARTED, RESUMED, CREATED]" (last lifecycle transition = "PRE_ON_CREATE")
  at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.waitForActivityToBecomeAnyOf(ActivityScenario.java:338)
...
```

Gradle then outputs:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: There were failing tests. See the report 
  at: file:///home/travis/build/Umweltzone/Umweltzone/Umweltzone/build/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DeviceProviderInstrumentTestTask.doTaskAction(DeviceProviderInstrumentTestTask.java:388)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(BaseTask.kt:63)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)
  ...
```

Full build log:

- https://app.travis-ci.com/github/Umweltzone/Umweltzone/jobs/547682552

The same tests successfully execute if I run them locally on a Pixel 2 device, Android 11 (SDK 30).
How can I fix the Travis CI / Android emulator configuration?

## Related

- [Activity never becomes requested state "[DESTROYED, RESUMED, STARTED, CREATED]" (last lifecycle transition = "PRE_ON_CREATE")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68534534/activity-never-becomes-requested-state-destroyed-resumed-started-created)
- [AndroidX.Test ActivityScenario: java.lang.AssertionError: Activity never becomes requested state "[RESUMED]" (last lifecycle transition = "STOPPED")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598321/androidx-test-activityscenario-java-lang-assertionerror-activity-never-becomes)
- [Android instrumented test throws exception: Activity never becomes requested state "[RESUMED, DESTROYED, STARTED, CREATED]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64458330/android-instrumented-test-throws-exception-activity-never-becomes-requested-sta)
- [How do I fix this error java.lang.AssertionError: Activity never becomes requested state "[DESTROYED]" (last lifecycle transition = "RESUMED")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67537197/how-do-i-fix-this-error-java-lang-assertionerror-activity-never-becomes-request)

Comment: Did you find a workaround?

Comment: No, I didn't. You can find my test branches for Travis CI still hanging around. Take a look.